# JSON.parse in IE7 with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I am using ExtJS 4.2 and am swapping key names in a JSON. JSON.parse() has a reviver function that does it for me clean, but this does not work in IE7. Is there a way to do this in ExtJS? decode,encode doesn't work.

```
    var parsed = JSON.parse(myJson, function(k, v) {
        if (k === "CITY")
            this.LOCATION = v;
        else if (k === "STATE")
            this.CTRYSTATE = v;
        else
            return v;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it, but wish there was a better solution.

```
myJson.LOCATION = myJson["NAME"];
delete myJson.NAME;
```